# Is there any reason why Frank Costello does not speak with an Irish accent?

Tags: the-departed

Similar to [this question here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/108982/is-there-any-reason-why-matthew-mcconaughey-does-not-speak-english-with-british), is there any reason why Frank Costello does not speak with an Irish accent in *The Departed*, like Pierce Brosnan does in *[The Foreigner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Foreigner_(2017_film))* (2017)?

In the film Costello grew up from an Irish Catholic family.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the same the world over, you speak the language and accent of where you were **raised** not that of your parents or grandparents.

Hennessy is an Irishman.

Costello is an American, of Irish ancestry.